# Как настроить snmp агент на роутере?

Tags: linux, консоль, роутер, snmp

Всем привет!
Впервые сталкиваюсь со службой snmp и ещё много чего не понимаю. Нужно наладить сообщение с роутером Totolink N150RT, чтобы по snmp получать информацию от него. В технической документации явно указана поддержка snmp, но в настройках на вебе соответствующего пункта найти не удалось. Подключившись к роутеру по telnet, удалось обнаружить файл /bin/snmpd.sh... И всё. Все советы по теме, что удалось нагуглить, направляют на службы и директории, которых тут, в маленькой версии линукса на роутере, нет. О менеджерах пакетов тоже речи не идёт.
Подумала, что, возможно, для роутера не требуется дополнительная конфигурация и попробовала обратиться к нему так: `snmpstatus -c public -v 2c 192.168.1.1`
Результат: `Timeout: No Response`
Попробовала, зайдя в файловую систему роутера по telnet, открыть порт 161, который snmp использует по умолчанию: `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT`
По запросу `iptables -L` новая конфигурация в таблице присутствует, но по команде `sudo nmap -p 161 192.168.1.1` отображается, что порт закрыт.
Возможно, я копаю не в том направлении. Конечная цель- наладить контакт с роутером по snmp v3, но для начала- получить хоть какой-то ответ по snmp, независимо от версии.
Кто сталкивался с похожей задачей, поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста.
Upd: прилагаю содержание скрипта snmpd.sh

```
if [ "$#" != "1" ]; then echo "Usage: $0 {start | stop | restart}"; exit 1 ; fi 

RETVAL=0 
GETMIB="flash get" 
CONFILE=/etc/net-snmp/snmpd.conf 
PIDFILE=/var/run/snmpd.pid 

if [ $1 = "stop" -o $1 = "restart" ]; then 
       # Stop snmpd. 
       if [ -f $PIDFILE ]; then 
               PID=`cat $PIDFILE` 
               if [ $PID != 0 ]; then 
                       kill -9 $PID 
                       RETVAL=$? 
                       if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]; then  
                               echo "Shutting down snmpd ... Success" 
                       else     
                               echo "Shutting down snmpd ... Fail" 
                       fi     
               fi 
               rm -f $PIDFILE 
       else 
               echo "Shutting down snmpd ... No snmpd running"  
       fi 
fi 

if [ $1 = "start" -a -f $PIDFILE ]; then 
       echo "Starting snmpd ... Already running" 
       exit 1 
fi       

if [ $1 = "start" -o $1 = "restart" ]; then 
       # Start snmpd. 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_ENABLED` 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_NAME` 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_LOCATION` 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_CONTACT` 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_RWCOMMUNITY` 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_ROCOMMUNITY` 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER1` 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER2` 
       eval `$GETMIB SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER3` 

       if [ $SNMP_ENABLED = 1 ]; then 
               echo "sysDescr DEFAULT" > $CONFILE 
               echo "sysObjectid  .1.3.6.1.4.1.28866.4.1" >> $CONFILE 
               echo "sysContact  $SNMP_CONTACT" >> $CONFILE 
               echo "sysName  $SNMP_NAME" >> $CONFILE 
               echo "sysLocation  $SNMP_LOCATION" >> $CONFILE 
               echo "sysServices  3" >> $CONFILE 
               echo "rocommunity  $SNMP_ROCOMMUNITY" >> $CONFILE 
               echo "rwcommunity  $SNMP_RWCOMMUNITY" >> $CONFILE 
               if [ "$SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER1" != "0.0.0.0" ]; then 
                       echo "trapsink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER1" >> $CONFILE 
                       echo "trap2sink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER1" >> $CONFILE 
                       echo "informsink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER1" >> $CONFILE 
               fi     
               if [ "$SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER2" != "0.0.0.0" ]; then 
                       echo "trapsink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER2" >> $CONFILE 
                       echo "trap2sink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER2" >> $CONFILE 
                       echo "informsink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER2" >> $CONFILE 
               fi     
               if [ "$SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER3" != "0.0.0.0" ]; then 
                       echo "trapsink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER3" >> $CONFILE 
                       echo "trap2sink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER3" >> $CONFILE 
                       echo "informsink  $SNMP_TRAP_RECEIVER3" >> $CONFILE 
               fi  

               echo "authtrapenable  1" >> $CONFILE 
               if [ "$DEBUG" = "1" ]; then      
                       snmpd -d -Lo -C -c $CONFILE -p $PIDFILE 
               else 
                       snmpd -Lf /dev/null -C -c $CONFILE -p $PIDFILE 
               fi       
               RETVAL=$? 
               if [ $RETVAL = 0 ]; then  
                       echo "Starting snmpd ... Success" 
               else     
                       echo "Starting snmpd ... Fail" 
               fi     
       fi 
fi 

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: Snmpd на роутере не запущен. Посмотри `ps`

Comment: Проверила- действительно не запущен. Мой вопрос как раз в том, как его запустить

Comment: Пробовала запустить `snmpd.sh start`, в ответ приходят сообщения `/bin/snmpd.sh: eval: line 1: Usage:: not found`, пока не остановишь процесс. После остановки- сообщение `sh: 1: unknown operand`

Comment: Ну раз `.sh`, то прям хорошо, если зальёшь содержимое скрипта в вопрос.

Comment: Дополнила вопрос скриптом. В файловой системе роутера по путям отсутствует папка `etc/net-snmp` и файл `var/run/snmpd.pid` Я предполагала, что причина ошибки может быть в этом. Но это значит, что либо перед запуском этого скрипта пропущен какой-то шаг, либо данная прошивка не пригодна для работы с snmp, а надежда, как известно, умирает последней